# Why won't my JPanel display?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am a newb trying to use my first layout manager in swing and can't get my JPanel to display and the window is minimised.. I have consulted the JavaDoc but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I just want a pointer in the right direction. I'm also connecting to my mysql database, but that's for another time. Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Here is my code

```
package learn;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class TestGUI3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{  
    JRadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
    JFrame f;  
    JButton b;
    JPanel myFirstPanel;
    public TestGUI3()
    {  
        f = new JFrame("Welcome to Ballon d'or , created by Darren Estcourt");  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myFirstPanel = new JPanel();
        f.add(myFirstPanel);
        rb1 = new JRadioButton("Start New Game");  
        rb2 = new JRadioButton("Load Game");
        rb3 = new JRadioButton("Quit");

        myFirstPanel.add(rb1);
        myFirstPanel.add(rb2);
        myFirstPanel.add(rb3);

        ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();  
        bg.add(rb1);
        bg.add(rb2);
        bg.add(rb3);  

        b = new JButton("OK");
        myFirstPanel.add(b);

        b.addActionListener(this);





        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
         f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  
          @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {  
                if(rb1.isSelected())
                {
                    f.dispose();


                  ManagerName test = new ManagerName();
                    test.getFrame().setVisible(true);

                }  
                if(rb2.isSelected())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Load Game");  
                } 
                if(rb3.isSelected())
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }  

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {  
                try
                {
                    String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
                    String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ballondor?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
                    Class.forName(myDriver);
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "Lucia290907");

                    String query = "SELECT * FROM clubInfo";

                    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                    while (rs.next())
                        {
                            int TeamID = rs.getInt("TeamID");
                            String TeamName = rs.getString("TeamName");
                            // print the results
                            System.out.format("%s, \n",  TeamName);
                        } // end while loop

                                    st.close();
                } // end try
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
              {
                  public void run() 
                  {
                  TestGUI3 test = new TestGUI3();
                  test.setVisible(true); 

                  }
              });
            }



}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that your class extends a JFrame as well as initializes one in its body?

Comment: Where is your main method that instantiates that JFrame? Then: you want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend the few minutes it takes to **properly** indent/format your source code - thanks!

Comment: Initially I just had an instance of JFrame and initialised it in my constructor. However I read about using the EDT and for whatever reason I cannot simply call my constructor via the EDT, because I had a "cannot find symbol" for the SetVisible() method. So, in order to remedy this, I extended the JFrame class and hopefully.....the program is running on the EDT.

Comment: As a tip, write @paul or whoever you want to notify that you made a reply (The `@` is important). And that's not making the program run in the EDT, the `SwingUtilities` that's running on the EDT but first post a [mcve] where we can see the same error about `"cannot find symbol"` you said above

Comment: The code you have provided is poorly written (and formatted incorrectly). I believe this is part of your problem and unfortunately we cannot rewrite your code for you. There is more than one problem with the code given however there are two answers below that will help you with the problem you have asked about.

Answer (score 2):

The order matters, I can't test right now but `BorderLayout` is the default layout manager on a Component, so, no need for this line:

```
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

I bet that when you remove the above line it will make a JButton appear and only because everything you're adding to your `JPanel` gets "overridden" by the new element added (because of `BorderLayout`) , if you want it to be vertical aligned then you might want to try `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout` with 1 column and 0 rows (not a typo, 0 rows means N rows) I can't post the links right now, but from the code I read on my phone that's my bet.

Also you're extending `JFrame` on your code and creating an instance of it, use one or the other, it's better to use the instance because if you extend `JFrame` that means your class **IS** a `JFrame`, if you need to extend something it's better to extend `JPanel`

But for better help sooner post a proper MCVE, i.e. post only the GUI code, we don't need the DB connection or the action performed, just the code where you're placing your components inside your JPanel